# jquery to loop through rows and perform a math function

Tags: jquery

I have a script that runs through a table, not ideal but I need to get it working.

The table fields `cubicmeters` and `cubesperbundle` are populated by an earlier script.

What I need to do, is now loop through the table and perform a math function on the inputs for each row.

I have a variable `rows` that has the number of rows and can be used for the variable I which will reference each row.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {

            var cubes = +$(this).closest('tr').find('input[name^="cubicmeters"+i]').val(); // reference the row 'i'
            var cubesperbundle = +$(this).closest('tr').find('input[name^="cubesperbundle"]').val();
            $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name^="bundles"]').val((cubes*cubesperbundle).toFixed(2));

}
```

A few things to note, this query is not in the head but inside a script tag at bottom of page. reason being that the table is populated with PHP so the head script will run before the inputs are loaded. as such I have put this script at the bottom of the page. In addition the jquery that populates `cubicmeters` and `cubesperbundle` only runs after the PHP populates the inputs that `cubicmeters` and `cubesperbundle` reply on to be populated.

so order: PHP populates a `productcode`. jquery (called from bottom of page) populates the `cubicmeters` and `cubesperbundle` fields based on the `productcode`. This must all happen on loading the page without any user trigger required.

Lastly, I need the jquery script to populate the `bundles` field with the result of `cubesperbundle`*`cubicmeters`

my html beofre this script must run is:

```
<table class="authors-list" border=0 id="ordertable">
    <tr>
        <td>Cubic Meters</td><td>Cubes per Bundle</td><td>Total Bundles</td>
    <tr>
       <td><input type="text" name="cubicmeters1" id="cubicmeters1" value="1.38"></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="cubesperbundle1" id="cubesperbundle1" value="1.485"></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="bundles1" id="bundles1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td><input type="text" name="cubicmeters2" id="cubicmeters2" value="1.38"></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="cubesperbundle2" id="cubesperbundle2" value="1.485"></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="bundles2" id="bundles2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td><input type="text" name="cubicmeters3" id="cubicmeters3" value="1.38"></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="cubesperbundle3" id="cubesperbundle3" value="1.485"></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="bundles3" id="bundles3"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

jsfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/WfemC/

This obviously is not working hence my question.

Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE**

```
for (var i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
    (function (index) {
        $.post('get_sku_cubes', {
            data: $('#product' + index).val()
        }, function (result) {
            $('#cubicmeters+ index).val(result);
        });
    })(i)
}

for (var i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
    (function (index) {
        $.post('get_cubesperbundle, {
            data: $('#product' + index).val()
        }, function (result) {
            $('#cubesperbundle+ index).val(result);
        });
    })(i)
}


$('#ordertable tr').each(function()
{
    var cubes = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name^="cubicmeters"]').val();

    var cubesperbundle = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name^="cubesperbundle"]').val();
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name^="totalbundles"]').val((cubes*cubesperbundle).toFixed(2));
});
```

Thanks

Comment: why you have added `+$(this)`?

Comment: Hi Dipesh, not 100% sure of ccorrect method. trying to identify the row in which the `cubicmeters+i` exists? Thanks for your tim

Comment: @DipeshParmar The line was `+$(this). ... .val()`. Since it's getting a value, it is a string. Adding a `+` in front casts it into a numeric value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it all wrong use `.each()` because `for` loop not getting `$(this)`

#### [Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WfemC/2/)

**EDIT**

**HTML**

```
<table class="authors-list" border=0 id="ordertable">
    <tr>
        <td>Cubic Meters</td><td>Cubes per Bundle</td><td>Total Bundles</td>
    <tr>
       <td><input type="text" name="cubicmeters1" id="cubicmeters1" value="1.38"></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="cubesperbundle1" id="cubesperbundle1" value="1.485"></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="bundles1" id="bundles1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td><input type="text" name="cubicmeters2" id="cubicmeters2" value="1.38"></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="cubesperbundle2" id="cubesperbundle2" value="1.485"></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="bundles2" id="bundles2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td><input type="text" name="cubicmeters3" id="cubicmeters3" value="1.38"></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="cubesperbundle3" id="cubesperbundle3" value="1.485"></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="bundles3" id="bundles3"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
$('#ordertable tr').each(function()
{
    var cubes           = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name^="cubicmeters"]').val();
    var cubesperbundle  = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name^="cubesperbundle"]').val();
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name^="bundles"]').val((cubes*cubesperbundle).toFixed(2));
});
```

Comment: Thanks Dipesh, this is not working on the link. the bundles field is not populated. Thanks

Comment: @Smudger well i can see its working and values are being set in total bundles fields....http://jsfiddle.net/WfemC/

Comment: Hi Dipesh, thanks for your help. This is not working on my side, as per the html output, the total bundles field is blank. correct link that we are viewing two different results?

Comment: Thanks Dipesh, this does work if I put an alert(cubes) inside the each loop. if I take it out it appears the script runs before the previous scipt to populate `cubicmeters` and `cubesperbundle` has finished running. how can I make this run afterwards. will show my updated syntax in the question.

Thanks again.

Comment: @Smudger you can do it using `.when()` and `.then()`....`$.when(forloopdone).then(.each code);`

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `.each()` function from jQuery to loop on each line, then you can use `$(this)` on each loop to work on the current line.

[Fiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/WfemC/4/)

**EDIT :** [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WfemC/5/) with separated functions

Comment: Thanks pdegand59, same issue as with dipesh. if I put an alert in the script, it works great. if I take out the alert, the script runs before the inputs cubicmeters and cubesperbundle are populated, so result is 0? How Can I dealy this till after the otehre script shave finished running?

Comment: How is the cubicmeters and cubesperbundle fields are populated ? If they are populated by Javascript functions, you could just put my code in a function then call it after the other populating functions. Check the updated fiddle in the original post !